# OR options using ruby "exists?"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to check if a User exists.

This works:

```
User.exists?(id:123) => true
```

However the ID won't be always available, just the "name_parameterized" column. So, How to do something like this?:

```
User.exists?("name_parameterized='peter-parker' OR id=123")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with two different queries, which is often faster due to indexing:

```
User.exists?(name_parameterized: 'peter-parker') or User.exists?(id: 123)
```

You could also collapse that into a single query, though that could be messier from a query optimizer perspective:

```
User.where(name_parameterized: 'peter-parker').or.where(id: 123).any?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
User.where(id: 123).or(User.where(name: 'peter-parker')).exists?
```

**Update**
This works in rails 5. For older versions use

```
User.where('id=? OR name=?', 123, 'peter-parker').exists?
```